# Don't throw it. You will break the fan

Tags: grammar

He was trying to throw the ball to the ceiling fan.

> "Don't throw it. You will break the fan."
>
> "Don't throw it. The fan will break."

Are the second sentence rephrase correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example is grammatical but unnatural, because using "break" intransitively strongly implies that the fan will break on its own, not because someone threw something at it or otherwise actively damaged it. You can say:

> Don't leave the fan running all day. It'll break.

because the connection between the action and the fan breaking is less direct, even though it's still a cause-effect relationship.

An informal way of expressing your original idea is:

> Hey, if you throw that you're going to break the fan.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is right. But it could be enriched by adding a conjunction. But still if you need the exact meaning as in the first sentence you should use the subject 
`YOU` in the second sentence.